# How to use subquery to populate column in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on an Access database which is used for forecasting purchases and I am trying to create a query in which would give me list of records with valid prices and row sums.

I am running into problems when I try to combine prices to quantities. I have following tables

Table that contains forecasting data (columns not relevant for this query omitted)

```
need_rows
ID  product_id  qty use_date
----------------------------
1   1           100 1.1.2014
2   1           50  15.1.2014
...
```

And table for prices

```
prices
ID  product_id  price   valid_from
----------------------------------
1   1           1       1.12.2013
2   1           2       24.12.2013
3   1           5       10.1.2014
...
```

Query resulst should be something like below:

```
result of query
product_id  use_date    qty price   sum
---------------------------------------
1           1.1.2014    100 2       200
1           15.1.2014   50  5       250
...
```

Meaning that I need to fetch valid price to each of the rows based on the use_date from need_rows and valid_from date from prices. Valid prices is the one that has valid_from date equal or most recent to use_date.

Below is one of the approaches I have tried with no luck.

```
SELECT prices.price
FROM prices
WHERE (((prices.product_id)=[product_id]) AND ((prices.valid_from)=
(SELECT Max(prices.valid_from) AS valid
FROM prices
WHERE (((prices.product_id)=[product_id]) AND ((prices.valid_from)<=[use_date]));).));
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT need_rows.Id
, need_rows.qty
, need_rows.product_id
, (SELECT TOP 1 price 
FROM prices 
WHERE need_rows.product_id = prices.product_id 
AND need_rows.use_date >= prices.valid_from 
ORDER BY prices.valid_from DESC) AS currentprice

FROM need_rows;
```